# Is there an elegant way to access protected members with gcc typeof & offsetof from outside the class?

Tags: c++, gcc, protected, typeof, offsetof

I'm working on a project written in both C and C++. The C part has a macro used to get a pointer to an object from a pointer to one of its members

```
#define START_OF_OBJ(ptr, type, member)({\
    const __typeof__(((type *)0)->member)* mptr = (ptr);\
    (type *)((char *)mptr - __builtin_offsetof(type, member)); })
```

It works fine for structs, but not as well with pointers to protected members of C++ classes. E.g. when compiling

```
class A {
    public:
        int a;
        int *getb() { return &b; }

    protected:
        int b;
};

int main(void)
{
    A obj;

    int *pb = obj.getb();

    A* a = START_OF_OBJ(pb, A, b);
}
```

with g++ -Wno-invalid-offsetof, it will - as expected - report errors for ((type *)0)->member and __builtin_offsetof(type, member) for accessing a protected member variable.

Is there a more elegant solution than making the function using the macro a class friend?

Comment: The general problem here is not the MACRO but the protected restriction itself. I am not aware of a solution to get access to protected members without having a friend class.

Comment: You might be interested by http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html. it allow to access to most private/protected stuff legally (without UB).

Comment: If you're going to do that you may as well just make everything public.

Comment: _"...The C part has a macro used to get a pointer to an object from a pointer to one of its members..."_ how do you expect a `C` program / macro to parse a `class` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten The macro is in a .h file, which compiles for both C and C++. When called with a class as a parameter, its from C++ code.

Comment: @Uri - If you want to access a variable from the outside, why make it protected in the first  place? And there really is no protection anyway, as you could do `*pb = 5;` and destroy the value.

Comment: Why do you actually need it? `&obj` is a pointer to the object and `pb` is a pointer to its member.

Comment: No, absolutely not. `offsetof` is a C thing; it doesn't work for types that are not [standard layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class).